# Calculate the net total of historical returns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello everyone I turn to StackOverflow community because I need to make a very specific sales query in an Invoicing App database.

The formula is based adding all records of items in the table `cash_billings_bills_articles`, subtracting the canceled items in the table `cash_billings_cancellations_articles`, but the problem is in the returns, returns can add or cancel at the same time. For example:

**Day 10/18/2015 records:**

[image]

**MY QUESTION**: 
In this day (10/18/2015) the return is `-76.00` making comparisons with his predecessor BillID for get net sales, but as I can do in mysql ?

**NOTE**: Only take the status rows: `Processed (1)`, `Outdated (4)` in `Returns`.

**The Model**:
[image]

**Table**: `cash_billings`
Store the main unique Invoice ID as cashbilling_id.

**Table**: `cash_billings_status`
Store the Invoice Status it can be:

```
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| cashbillingstatus_id  | cashbillingstatus_name |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| 1                     | Processed              | 
| 2                     | Pending                | 
| 3                     | Removed                |
| 4                     | Outdated               | 
+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

**Table**: `cash_billings_bills`, `cash_billings_returns`, `cash_billings_cancellations`:
Store documents information like:

**Column**: `cashbillingbill_id`, `cashbillingreturn_id`, `cashbillingcancellation_id`
Store the document reference.

**Column**: `cashbilling_id`
Main unique invoice id.

**Column**: `cashbillingbillstatus_id`, `cashbillingreturnstatus_id`, `cashbillingcancellationstatus_id`
Status of the billings

**Column**: `cashbillingbill_extracharge`
The extra charges of bills, returns, cancellations.

**Column**: `cashbillingbill_date`, `cashbillingreturn_date`, `cashbillingcancellation_date`: 
Date of creation.

**Table**: `cash_billings_bills_articles`
Store the items sold.

**Table**: `cash_billings_returns_articles`
Store the items returned or sold.

**Table**: `cash_billings_cancellations_articles`
Store the items cancelled.

This is my code:

```
SELECT  
    COALESCE(
                SUM(
                        CASE 
                            WHEN cash_billings_BRC_articles.cashbillingtype_id = 1 THEN 
                                cashbillingBRCarticle_total 
                            END
                    ), 
            0.00) AS cashbillingBRCarticle_bills,
    -- 0 AS cashbillingBRCarticle_returns,
    COALESCE(
                SUM(
                        CASE 
                            WHEN cash_billings_BRC_articles.cashbillingtype_id = 3 THEN 
                                cashbillingBRCarticle_total 
                            END
                    ), 
            0.00) AS cashbillingBRCarticle_cancellations,
    cash_billings_BRC.cashbilling_extracharge,
    -- 0 AS cashbillingBRC_netsale,
    DATE_FORMAT(cash_billings_BRC_articles.cashbillingBRC_date, '%d/%m/%Y') AS cashbillingBRC_date
FROM (
    SELECT 
        (1) AS cashbillingtype_id,
        cash_billings_bills.cashbillingbill_id AS cashbillingBRC_id,
        cash_billings_bills.cashbillingbillstatus_id AS cashbillingBRCstatus_id,
        cash_billings_bills_articles.article_id,
        cash_billings_bills_articles.cashbillingbillarticle_sellprice AS cashbillingBRCarticle_sellprice,
        cash_billings_bills_articles.cashbillingbillarticle_quantity AS cashbillingBRCarticle_quantity,
        cash_billings_bills_articles.cashbillingbillarticle_discount AS cashbillingBRCarticle_discount,
        cash_billings_bills_articles.cashbillingbillarticle_isv AS cashbillingBRCarticle_isv,
        cash_billings_bills_articles.cashbillingbillarticle_total AS cashbillingBRCarticle_total,
        cash_billings_bills.cashbillingbill_extracharge AS cashbillingBRC_extracharge,
        cash_billings_bills.cashbillingbill_date AS cashbillingBRC_date
    FROM cash_billings_bills_articles
        LEFT JOIN cash_billings_bills USING(cashbillingbill_id)
    WHERE cash_billings_bills.cashbillingbillstatus_id IN (1, 4) -- Proceed, Outdated
    UNION
    SELECT
        (2) AS cashbillingtype_id,
        cash_billings_returns.cashbillingreturn_id AS cashbillingBRC_id,
        cash_billings_returns.cashbillingreturnstatus_id AS cashbillingBRCstatus_id,
        cash_billings_returns_articles.article_id,
        cash_billings_returns_articles.cashbillingreturnarticle_sellprice AS cashbillingBRCarticle_sellprice,
        cash_billings_returns_articles.cashbillingreturnarticle_quantity AS cashbillingBRCarticle_quantity,
        cash_billings_returns_articles.cashbillingreturnarticle_discount AS cashbillingBRCarticle_discount,
        cash_billings_returns_articles.cashbillingreturnarticle_isv AS cashbillingBRCarticle_isv,
        cash_billings_returns_articles.cashbillingreturnarticle_total AS cashbillingBRCarticle_total,
        cash_billings_returns.cashbillingreturn_extracharge AS cashbillingBRC_extracharge,
        cash_billings_returns.cashbillingreturn_date AS cashbillingBRC_date
    FROM cash_billings_returns_articles
        LEFT JOIN cash_billings_returns USING(cashbillingreturn_id)
    UNION
    SELECT 
        (3) AS cashbillingtype_id,
        cash_billings_cancellations.cashbillingcancellation_id AS cashbillingBRC_id,
        cash_billings_cancellations.cashbillingcancellationstatus_id AS cashbillingBRCstatus_id,
        cash_billings_cancellations_articles.article_id,
        cash_billings_cancellations_articles.cashbillingcancellationarticle_sellprice AS cashbillingBRCarticle_sellprice,
        cash_billings_cancellations_articles.cashbillingcancellationarticle_quantity AS cashbillingBRCarticle_quantity,
        cash_billings_cancellations_articles.cashbillingcancellationarticle_discount AS cashbillingBRCarticle_discount,
        cash_billings_cancellations_articles.cashbillingcancellationarticle_isv AS cashbillingBRCarticle_isv,
        cash_billings_cancellations_articles.cashbillingcancellationarticle_total AS cashbillingBRCarticle_total,
        cash_billings_cancellations.cashbillingcancellation_extracharge AS cashbillingBRC_extracharge,
        cash_billings_cancellations.cashbillingcancellation_date AS cashbillingBRC_date
    FROM cash_billings_cancellations_articles
        LEFT JOIN cash_billings_cancellations USING(cashbillingcancellation_id)
        WHERE cash_billings_cancellations.cashbillingcancellationstatus_id IN (1) -- Proceed
) cash_billings_BRC_articles
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        ROUND(SUM(cash_billings_BRC.cashbillingbill_extracharge), 2) AS cashbillingbill_extracharge,
        ROUND(SUM(cash_billings_BRC.cashbillingreturn_extracharge), 2) AS cashbillingreturn_extracharge,
        ROUND(SUM(cash_billings_BRC.cashbillingcancellation_extracharge), 2) AS cashbillingcancellation_extracharge,
        ROUND((SUM(cash_billings_BRC.cashbillingbill_extracharge) + SUM(cash_billings_BRC.cashbillingreturn_extracharge) - SUM(cash_billings_BRC.cashbillingcancellation_extracharge)), 2) AS cashbilling_extracharge,
        cash_billings_BRC.cashbilling_date
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            SUM(cashbillingbill_extracharge) AS cashbillingbill_extracharge,
            0.00 AS cashbillingreturn_extracharge,
            0.00 AS cashbillingcancellation_extracharge,
            cashbillingbill_date AS cashbilling_date
            FROM cash_billings_bills
        WHERE cash_billings_bills.cashbillingbillstatus_id IN (1, 4) -- Processed, Outdated
        GROUP BY 
            YEAR(cash_billings_bills.cashbillingbill_date), 
            MONTH(cash_billings_bills.cashbillingbill_date), 
            DAY(cash_billings_bills.cashbillingbill_date)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            0.00 AS cashbillingbill_extracharge,
            SUM(cashbillingreturn_extracharge) AS cashbillingreturn_extracharge,
            0.00 AS cashbillingcancellation_extracharge,
            cashbillingreturn_date AS cashbilling_date
        FROM cash_billings_returns
        WHERE cash_billings_returns.cashbillingreturnstatus_id IN (1, 4) -- Processed, Outdated
        GROUP BY 
            YEAR(cash_billings_returns.cashbillingreturn_date), 
            MONTH(cash_billings_returns.cashbillingreturn_date), 
            DAY(cash_billings_returns.cashbillingreturn_date)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            0.00 AS cashbillingbill_extracharge,
            0.00 AS cashbillingreturn_extracharge,
            SUM(cashbillingcancellation_extracharge) AS cashbillingcancellation_extracharge,
            cashbillingcancellation_date AS cashbilling_date
        FROM cash_billings_cancellations
        WHERE cash_billings_cancellations.cashbillingcancellationstatus_id IN (1) -- Processed
        GROUP BY 
            YEAR(cash_billings_cancellations.cashbillingcancellation_date), 
            MONTH(cash_billings_cancellations.cashbillingcancellation_date), 
            DAY(cash_billings_cancellations.cashbillingcancellation_date)
    ) AS cash_billings_BRC
    GROUP BY 
        YEAR(cash_billings_BRC.cashbilling_date), 
        MONTH(cash_billings_BRC.cashbilling_date), 
        DAY(cash_billings_BRC.cashbilling_date)
    ORDER BY cash_billings_BRC.cashbilling_date ASC
) cash_billings_BRC
ON DATE_FORMAT(cash_billings_BRC.cashbilling_date,'%m-%d-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(cash_billings_BRC_articles.cashbillingBRC_date,'%m-%d-%Y')
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(cash_billings_BRC_articles.cashbillingBRC_date), 
    MONTH(cash_billings_BRC_articles.cashbillingBRC_date), 
    DAY(cash_billings_BRC_articles.cashbillingBRC_date)
ORDER BY cash_billings_BRC_articles.cashbillingBRC_date ASC;
```

I need to show this result (see `return` column):
[image]

Database drum data:
[Download](http://gozfly.com/sql/DataDump.sql)

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far, and describe what's wrong with that query?

Comment: Of course please see my Question again.

Comment: And what is wrong with your query? Please add details.

Comment: Table aliases are great to make queries easier to write and easier to read!!!

Comment: At least some of the LEFT JOINs executes as regular INNER JOINs here. E.g. LEFT JOIN cash_billings_cancellations has a WHERE condition cash_billings_cancellations.cashbillingcancellationstatus_id IN (1), which means right site table values are required -> it's an inner join. If you want true LEFT JOIN result, move that condition to the ON clause instead! (Or switch to INNER JOIN, if that's what you want.)

Comment: I need to calculate the cashbillingBRCarticle_returns and cashbillingBRC_extracharges per day. 
I have attached the code of the database structure and the desired information.

Comment: If you remove all irrelevant tables and columns and provide an example of source data in a plain text that is easy to copy-paste, not as an image, your chances of getting a good answer would increase dramatically. I'd recommend to use http://sqlfiddle.com to create a sample simplified schema and sample data and output. It would also help to understand your question if you explained step-by-step your formulas and logic.

Comment: Does `cashbillingreturnarticle_sellprice * cashbillingreturnarticle_quantity - cashbillingreturnarticle_discount [some operation to do with ISV ] = cashbillingreturnarticle_total`?  If not, then what is ISV in this context and how does it relate to the other fields?

Comment: FWIW, I think your previous version of the question which included the expected summary values was better.  Or at least, given I produced my answer based on the previous version of your question, I would therefore suggest you perhaps revert the latest edits to at least re-include that and then maybe add the additional information you have above as well if you like.  (I to solve your question based primarily on the previous model summary answer and the mysql dump you gave.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The follow query gives you exactly the model answer you posted, except for the date of 2015-10-18 (remarks about that below):

```
select   
  sum(bills) bills, 
  sum(`returns`) `returns`, 
  sum(cancellations) cancellations, 
  sum(extracharges) extracharges,
  coalesce(sum(bills),0.0) + coalesce(sum(`returns`),0.0) + coalesce(sum(cancellations),0.0) + coalesce(sum(extracharges),0.0) nettotal,
  `date`
from
  (
    /* Retrieve bills values from articles table by bill date. 
       Question: Why is this not the same as the value when you look at cashbillingbill_nettotal instead? */
    select
      date(b.cashbillingbill_date) `date`, 
      a.cashbillingbillarticle_total bills, 
      null `returns`,
      null cancellations,
      null extracharges
    from
      cash_billings_bills_articles a
    inner join
      cash_billings_bills b on a.cashbillingbill_id = b.cashbillingbill_id

    union all

    /* Retrieve bills extra charges values from bills table, by bill date. */  
    select
      date(b.cashbillingbill_date) `date`, 
      null bills,
      null `returns`,
      null cancellations,
      b.cashbillingbill_extracharge extracharges
    from
      cash_billings_bills b

    union all   

    /* Retrieve returns values from returns table, by return date. */
    select 
      date(cashbillingreturn_date) `date`,
      null bills,
      cashbillingreturn_nettotal `returns`, 
      null cancellations,
      cashbillingreturn_extracharge extracharges
    from 
      cash_billings_returns
    where
      cashbillingreturnstatus_id in (1,4)

    union all  

    /* Retrieve cancellations from cancellations table by cancellation date */
    select
      date(cashbillingcancellation_date) `date`, 
      null bills,
      null `returns`,
      cashbillingcancellation_nettotal cancellations,
      null extracharges  
    from
      cash_billings_cancellations
  ) detailvalues
group by
  `date`
order by
  `date`;
```

Regarding the 2015-10-18 returns value, I'm not entirely clear why you expect the returns value on 2015-10-18 to be 76.0, as the values for that date is as follows:

```
/* returns values for 2015-10-18 */
select 
  sum(cashbillingreturn_nettotal) `returns`,
  sum(cashbillingreturn_extracharge) extracharges
from 
  cash_billings_returns
where
  cashbillingreturnstatus_id in (1,4)
  and date(cashbillingreturn_date) = '2015-10-18';
```

This returns

```
returns extracharges
79.45   3.45
```

Notice that 79.45 - 3.45 = 76, which is what you're expecting in your model answer, however, in every other row in my answer, "extracharges" were accounted for separately from the returns value (meaning it was accounted for under the "extracharges" column) and it matched your expectation correctly.

This leads me to conclude that the above values (79.45 and 3.45 separate and not netted to 76) is the correct way (for your requirements) to handle the returns values in general, and consequently that expecting the returns on this day to be 76 is perhaps (?) a mistaken expectation given that everything else matches exactly.